# How to solve this private connection issue?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

Whenever i try to access cpanel of my following website it displays below error.

**This server could not prove that it is growthjob.com. Its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.**

I can connect to it by clicking proceed but my notepad++ throws 
**Failure retrieving contents of directory /**.

Comment: What doest ssllabs.com says about your server?